# Wrong usernames on the Winter Bash /stats page

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, winter-bash-2021

In the [public WB stats](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/stats) page, the usernames are incorrect. For example, "user1599751" is PeterJ, "user163529" is Shree, "user51" is Yaakov Ellis and so on.

Comment: I think the ID listing might've caused this error. As someone who is not yet a moderator, I can't be sure of this.

Comment: You don't need to be a moderator to see someone's UID. And it dosen't actually help :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syncing of display names between the sites and the WB mini-site doesn't always work. I have manually fixed the final stats for WB2021 (but this could very well happen again next year, since the less-than-perfect sync is a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) type issue).